# How do I bind JSON responses to button actions on webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I wrote Javascript code that queries a Tableau server API for running jobs. The returned jobs are displayed on a web page with a button associated with each job that allows the user to kill that specific job.

The script works fine if there is only one job running but if there are multiple jobs running, the selected kill button is stopping a different job than one you are intending to kill.
[Screen shot of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBgmM.png)

I have included the entire code chain and a sample of the JSON response for reference.

JSON Response example from server:

```json
{
    "pagination": {
        "pageNumber": "1",
        "pageSize": "100",
        "totalAvailable": "2"
    },
    "backgroundJobs": {
        "backgroundJob": [
            {
                "id": "d17901fe-7fc5-4c3c-95ff-7013102b56b0",
                "status": "Pending",
                "createdAt": "2021-04-02T16:08:09Z",
                "priority": "0",
                "jobType": "refresh_extracts"
            },
            {
                "id": "e91ab533-8050-4341-8ac9-9f3429d03718",
                "status": "Pending",
                "createdAt": "2021-04-02T16:08:09Z",
                "priority": "0",
                "jobType": "refresh_extracts"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```js
    function getToken() {

      fetch('https://tableau.bjc.org/api/3.4/auth/signin', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "credentials": {
                "name": "login",
                "password": "Password",
                "site": {
                    "contentUrl": "Default"
                }
            }
        })
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json()
    }).then(function (data) {

        token = data.credentials.token;
        siteId = data.credentials.site.id;
        userId = data.credentials.user.id;

        return data;

    }
    ).then(function () {
        return fetch('https://tableau.server/api/3.4/sites/' + siteId + '/jobs?filter=status:eq:InProgress&fields=_all_', {
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                "X-Tableau-Auth": token
            },
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.json()
        }).then(function (data) {
            jobs = [data];

            if (jobs[0].backgroundJobs.backgroundJob.length == 0) {

                var noJobs = document.createElement("H4");
                noJobs.innerText = "There are no jobs in progress."
                document.getElementById("bee-alert").appendChild(noJobs);
                //document.body.appendChild(noJobs);

            }

            for (let i = 0; i < jobs[0].backgroundJobs.backgroundJob.length; i++) {

                jobId = jobs[0].backgroundJobs.backgroundJob[i].id;
                name = jobs[0].backgroundJobs.backgroundJob[i].title;
                startTime = jobs[0].backgroundJobs.backgroundJob[i].startedAt;
                status = jobs[0].backgroundJobs.backgroundJob[i].status;
                jobType = jobs[0].backgroundJobs.backgroundJob[i].jobType;


                //Grab the main table and assign it to variable
                var $table = $('#bee-table');


                //append a body to the table
                var $tbody = $table.append('<tbody />').children('tbody');

                // add row
                $tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last')
                    .append('<td>' + name + '</td>')
                    .append('<td>' + jobId + '</td>')
                    .append('<td>' + startTime + '</td>')
                    .append('<td>' + status + '</td>')
                    .append('<td>' + jobType + '</td>')
                    .append('<td><button id="bee-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">End This Job</button><div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header bg-danger"><h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style="color:#ffffff;"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Stop Running Job</h5> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div><div class="modal-body">Are you sure you want to stop this job from running?</div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button><button id="kill-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Stop Job</button></td> </div></div></div></div>');

                //append all of the above elements to the table
                $table.appendTo('#bee-table');



                var btn = document.getElementById("kill-btn");

                // btn.onclick = killFunction;
                btn.onclick = function () {
                    killFunction();
                    pageRefresh();

                };




                function killFunction() {

                    return fetch('https://tableau.server/api/3.4/sites/' + siteId + '/jobs/' + jobId, {
                        method: 'PUT',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            "X-Tableau-Auth": token
                        },
                    }).then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response.status);
                        return response.json()
                    });



                }
            }

        })
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your current solution into this.

What I did is attach a dataset(`data-job-id`) to the terminate button then attach a `click` listener to the table's body then use the `end-background-job` class name to determine if the button triggered the click.

```js
const fakeResponse = {
  pagination: { pageNumber: "1", pageSize: "100", totalAvailable: "2" },
  backgroundJobs: {
    backgroundJob: [
      {
        id: "d17901fe-7fc5-4c3c-95ff-7013102b56b0",
        status: "Pending",
        createdAt: "2021-04-02T16:08:09Z",
        priority: "0",
        jobType: "refresh_extracts"
      },
      {
        id: "e91ab533-8050-4341-8ac9-9f3429d03718",
        status: "Pending",
        createdAt: "2021-04-02T16:08:09Z",
        priority: "0",
        jobType: "refresh_extracts"
      }
    ]
  }
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const $table = document.getElementById('jobs-table');
  const endBackgroundJobClassName = 'end-background-job';

  // Do the API request here
  const terminateJob = (jobId) => {
    if(confirm(`Remove job ${jobId}`)) {
      // simulate API call
      setTimeout(() => document.getElementById(jobId).remove(), 500);
    }
  };

  $table.addEventListener('click', e => {
     const el = e.target;
    
    if(Array.from(el.classList).includes(endBackgroundJobClassName)) {
      terminateJob(el.dataset?.jobId);
    }
  });
  
  const markup = fakeResponse.backgroundJobs.backgroundJob.reduce((rawHtml, job) => {
    
    rawHtml += `
      <tr id=${job.id}>
        <th>Job name here</th>
        <td>${job.id}</td>
        <td>${job.createdAt}</td>
        <td>${job.status}</td>
        <td>${job.jobType}</td>
        <td>
          <button data-job-id="${job.id}" type="button" class="btn btn-warning ${endBackgroundJobClassName}">End this job</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    `;
   
    return rawHtml;
  }, '');

  $table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
});
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Job Name</th>
      <th>Job ID</th>
      <th>Time Started</th>
      <th>Current Status</th>
      <th>Job Type</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="jobs-table">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, karlmarxlopez! It took me some time trying trying to incorporate your recommendations into my code but I eventually got it to work.  Thank you so much.